# Options for CD burning libraries?

Tags: language-agnostic, cd-burning

I'm looking to create a program that will burn an audio CD. Before diving in I was hoping to see a selection of libraries that will make writing the code to burn the audio easy to write. I don't care much about language but something that is cross OS would be nice. (Specifically Windows and linux).

So far the only library that I see is PrimoBurn, but I can't seem to get their C++ version to compile.

So what do you guys use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good dvd burning component for Windows or .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930/what-is-a-good-dvd-burning-component-for-windows-or-net) and [Burn CD/DVD from C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870474/burn-cd-dvd-from-c-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cdrecord](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) runs on both Windows and Linux (Mac as well). Call it through a system call.

Comment: +1 since cdrecord is the best CD recording application ever.

Comment: Fair enough, this seems to be my only option :( Hopefully it doesn't end up being as hacky as I think that it will be.